# Encoding: Can I have more than one million combinations out of a 6 digit integer?

Tags: compression

Is there any magical compression algorithm / technique to get me more than 1,000,000 combinations out of a 6-digit code ("123456")?

I.e. can I compress integers into integers?

Comment: less than one tenth of our expectation may be achieved with permutations, but if you insist on combinations, simply, no.

Comment: Despite a [really strong XY smell](http://xyproblem.info/): assuming you're talking about a 6 digit code stored as 6 bytes (eg in ascii): would using a hex string or base 64 be an acceptable approach?